# Is there an idiomatic way to operate on 2 arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, iterator, ruby-1.9.3, enumerable

```
a = [3, 4, 7, 8, 3]
b = [5, 3, 6, 8, 3]
```

Assuming arrays of same length, is there a way to use `each` or some other idiomatic way to get a result from each element of both arrays? Without using a counter?

For example, to get the product of each element: `[15, 12, 42, 64, 9]`

`(0..a.count - 1).each do |i|` is so ugly...

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For performance reasons, `zip` may be better, but `transpose` keeps the symmetry and is easier to understand.

```
[a, b].transpose.map{|a, b| a * b}
# => [15, 12, 42, 64, 9]
```

A difference between `zip` and `transpose` is that in case the arrays do not have the same length, the former inserts `nil` as a default whereas the latter raises an error. Depending on the situation, you might favor one over the other.

Answer (score 6):

What about using [`Array.zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
>> a = [3,4,7,8,3]
=> [3, 4, 7, 8, 3]
>> b = [5,3,6,8,3]
=> [5, 3, 6, 8, 3]
>> c = []
=> []
>> a.zip(b) do |i, j| c << i * j end
=> [[3, 5], [4, 3], [7, 6], [8, 8], [3, 3]]
>> c
=> [15, 12, 42, 64, 9]
```

Note: I am very much *not* a Ruby programmer so I apologize for any idioms that I have trampled all over.

Comment: was about to write it. that's the way I would do it :)

Comment: @Castilho: my first thought was, damn... Ruby has to have a `zip` method somewhere.  I come from Python land so it took a few seconds to find it.

Comment: Braces are generally used with one-liners (`a.zip(b).each { |i, j| c << i * j }`) but that's not exactly *trampling*. And `map` would be more appropriate in this specific case: `c = a.zip(b).map { ... }`

Comment: You can  just do `a.zip(b) do ... end` to avoid creating the intermediate array, which might be useful for large arrays.

Comment: @matt: I was wondering whether `each` was required or not.  I didn't realize that `each` introduced another `Array`.  I'll change that.